# How to server undeafen a member in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to automatically undeafen members in my server with a bot.

I know that I can unmute a member with `member.edit(mute = False)` so I thought that I could use the following command: `member.edit(deaf = False)` since `deaf` is an attribute of `VoiceState` just like `deaf` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        if after.mute:
            await member.edit(mute = False)
            
        if after.deaf:
            await member.edit(deaf = False)
```

The "mute" part works and the `if after.deaf:` works too, so the problem is with `await member.edit(deaf = False)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `deaf` but `deafen`

```py
await member.edit(deafen=False)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit)